# How to put the image mage on the top left side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm a complete novice here,  I want to put the vault-tec image on the left side aligned with the navigation menu,

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="/images/vault-tec.png" alt="vault-tec-logo" />
        <div class="home">Home</div>
        <div class="about">About</div>
        <div class="services">Services</div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here's the css input:

```
`
.container {
    background-color: #35538b;
    height: 300px;
}

.navbar {
    gap: 50px;
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: monospace;
    align-items: center;
    color: #eac852;
}
.navbar img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    justify-content: flex-start;`
```

I tried with the flex properties `display`, `align-item...`it's not working, I want to know what exactly I'm doing wrong. I attached an image for reference.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use align-self and margin-right to align the image to the top left side, your CSS code should look like this:

```
.navbar img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    align-self: flex-start;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, to have more control of the photo in the space you can use in the `.navbar img` class also `position:absolute` (inserting `position:relative` in the `.container` class).

Comment: Yes, thank you so much this is exactly where I want to have the logo. I've been learning for few days, spent most of the time on flex box.

Answer (score 0):

Is that how you want it to be? Did I get right?

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.container {
    background-color: #35538b;
    height: 300px;
}

.navbar {
    gap: 50px;
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: monospace;
    align-items: center;
    color: #eac852;
}
.navbar .logo {
    padding:15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
.logo img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9604815/pexels-photo-9604815.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="vault-tec-logo" /> 
      </div>
        <div class="home">Home</div>
        <div class="about">About</div>
        <div class="services">Services</div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```